# Can't Set Static IP - Ubuntu 14.04.03 - Server

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, static-ip

I am configuring a few servers all with the same basic configuration.

We first set the DNS/Domain in /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base

```
cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
domain domain.com
search domain.com
nameserver 10.1.8.1

cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.1.10.11
        netmask 255.255.252.0
        network 10.1.8.0
        broadcast 10.1.11.255
        gateway 10.1.8.1
```

This is the configuration on a working server, but when I replicate it to the other two servers, I get nothing, but it works if i set DHCP. What else could I be missing?

Note : We also ran the following to get the names back to eth0

```
echo y | sudo apt-get remove biosdevname
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

I think this is a UEFI thing with the new nic naming convention, not sure if that had any effect, but it was done on the working machines as well.

Comment: In most caces just _address_, _netmask_ and _gateway_ options are needed, what happens if you comment the other ones out?